# Default constructor for Fragment in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a fragment class that looks like this:

```
public class MessageFragment extends Fragment {
    Context ctx;
    Button compose;

    public MessageFragment(Context ctx){
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }
...}
```

The constructor it gives an error that says

> This fragment should provide a default constructor

Meanwhile, I have 4 other fragment classes that are formatted this exact way, but they don't give this error. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5):

When your `Activity` is recreated due to a configuration change (such as an orientation change), the system will manage recreating the state of your fragments by creating a new instance of your `Fragment`, and then passing the arguments in using `setArguments(Bundle args)`. It uses the *default* constructor to recreate your fragment, which is why it is required. You should *never* rely on logic that happens in a non-default constructor for your fragment, as you'll immediately break on a configuration change.

Also, passing in a `Context` to your `Fragment` seems like a memory leak waiting to happen. It might not, but it's not good practice. Wait until one of the `Fragment` lifecycle events such as `onCreate()` or `onAttach()`, and store a reference to `getActivity()` as your `Context`. You can then release the reference in `onDetach()`.

EDIT: Basically, anything you need to pass in for your `Fragment` to function properly should either be stored in its arguments `Bundle`, or saved in the `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)` event and restored in `onCreate(Bundle state)`, otherwise you'll lose it on a config change.

This is why there's a common pattern of a static factory method for creating fragments. For example:

```
public static Fragment newInstance(String arg1, int arg2) {
    Fragment result = new MyFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("arg1_key", arg1);
    args.putInt("arg2_key", arg2);
    result.setArguments(args); 
    return result;
}
```

And then use that instead of a non-default constructor. From within your `Fragment` you can then retrieve the data with:

```
Bundle args = getArguments();
String arg1 = args.getString("arg1_key");
int arg2 = args.getInt("arg2_key");
```

Comment: Added another example for clarity.

Comment: do you then keep constructor public or private? In Java you would make it private but in this case Android Lint complains "The default constructor must be public"

Comment: Due to the Fragment framework implementation, you have to keep it public.

Comment: @KevinCoppock But what is this restriction backed by that causes it to show up? That's what I'm curious about. In `Fragment`'s default constructor there is no annotation or something that tells the compiler that inheritors' default constructor's visibility must not be narrowed.

Comment: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-1.0-dev/fragment/src/main/java/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment.java#435

Answer (score 0):

Just add a default constructor like this

```
public MessageFragment(){}
```

And you should be good.

Comment: If you're relying on the `ctx` variable, you'll get a crash as soon as you rotate the device this way.

Comment: also andoids eclipse lint tool will throw that error when you have a non default constructor in your fragment. In that case when your done adding to your fragment class just clean your project and it will fix itself

Comment: Now it says "avoid non-default constructors in fragments; use a default constructor plus Fragment#setArguments(Bundle) instead"

Comment: You should also take kcoppock's advice and just use getActivity() instead of passing context.

Comment: Yeah the only time I ever use a non default constructor into a fragment is to pass in an interface or something.